# Webview prevent scroll up from specific height

Tags: android, webview

I have one webview. I know how to programmatically scroll down it when page is loaded.
My problem is that I want to prevent the user from scrolling up at the place that I programmatically scrolled down.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of programmatically scroll down do those changes in xml.

```
<WebView
        android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

This will crop the content that you want to hide from top

Answer (score 1):

Use following:

```
WebView wv = new WebView(this);
wv.setFocusable(false);
```

and to make it clickable again:

```
wv.setFocusable(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can prevent Just add setEnabled(false)